# Taylor series of product of two functions

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

let $f$ and $g$ be infinitley differentiable functions and $a_k = \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}$ and $b_e = \frac{g^{(e)}(a)}{e!}$ be cofficients of Taylor Polynomial at $a$ then what would be the coefficients of $fg$.

rather than asking my specific question I asked this general question so other can benefit too

So I think we would need to multiply the two polynomials but that's just my intuition and I don't know how to justify it and I don't think it would be as simple.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $b_e=\frac{g^{(e)}(a)}{e!}$ ? If so, look up the [Cauchy Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your intuition is good.

Multiplying the series gives an n-th term coefficient of

$$c_n  = a_0b_n + a_1b_{n-1} + \dots + a_{n-1}b_1 + a_nb_0= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_{n-i}$$

which is the same as doing the Taylor series of $fg$ the long way, since

$$c_n = \frac{(fg)^{(n)}(a)}{n!} = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}f^{(i)}(a)g^{(n-i)}(a)}{n!} = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!} \frac{g^{(n-i)}(a)}{(n-i)!} = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_{n-i}$$

Comment: In words: the coefficients of the product of two power series is the *convolution* of the coefficients of the factors.